# WP8 bind an object array to checkbox

Tags: windows-phone-8

How to bind an array with a checkbox visibility.

I was initially using a visibilityconverter for binding one object but how do i bind it with more than one objects, as now the visibility depends on more than one parameters.

Any clue as to how to bind a object[] to checkbox in a listbox in wp8

Comment: where the `object[]` is come from? You can define another converter to convert `object[]` into Visibility.

Comment: that I have to form and bind to checkbox. I need something like a multibinding. But on searching I found that multibinding using IMultiBinding is not supported in WP8

Answer (score 0):

I'd create an additional property and bind my checkbox's visibility to it:

```
public Visibility checkboxVisibility
{
    get
    {
        return (condition) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to notify checkbox when checkboxVisibility value might change- when you modify any object included in *condition* use(after implementing INotifyPropertyChanged interface):

```
NotifyPropertyChanged("checkboxVisibility");
```